# how to get an itemprop element value with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cheerio

I am trying for the first time cheerio library to do a little bit of web scraping from paginas amarillas, such as companies name, address etc... The address is in a span inside a span with no class, only an `itemprop="streetAddres"`, I have tried different ways as it is a long string to get to that selector, I get data until the one right before the itemprop but I do not know how to aim the itemprop selector, the one I am having troubles with is the pathAddreses constant it returns an empty array on the console log, if I delete the last element of the string(`itemprop='streetAddres'`) it brings me data but not exactly the one I want

Here is the code:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request-promise");
//const of the classes of the paginas amarillas elements we are aiming to
const pathProfesionals1 =
  ".container .row .first-content-listado .col-lg-7.col-md-8.col-xs-12 .bloque-central .central .listado-item.item-ip .box .cabecera .row .col-xs-11.comercial-nombre a h2 span";
const pathProfesionals2 =
  ".container .row .first-content-listado .col-lg-7.col-md-8.col-xs-12 .bloque-central .central .listado-item.item-ig .box .cabecera .row .col-xs-11.comercial-nombre a h2 span";
const pathTelephones1 =
  ".container .row .first-content-listado .col-lg-7.col-md-8.col-xs-12 .bloque-central .central .listado-item.item-ip .box .pie-pastilla .row .col-xs-4 a.llama-desplegable.btn.btn-amarillo.btn-block.phone.hidden.d-none span";
const pathTelephones2 =
  ".container .row .first-content-listado .col-lg-7.col-md-8.col-xs-12 .bloque-central .central .listado-item.item-ig .box .pie-pastilla .row .col-xs-4 a.llama-desplegable.btn.btn-amarillo.btn-block.phone.hidden.d-none span";
const pathAddress1 = `.container .row .first-content-listado .col-lg-7.col-md-8.col-xs-12 .bloque-central .central .listado-item.item-ig .box .row a .location span *[itemprop = 'streetAddress']`;

const pathAddress2 = "";

init = async () => {
    const arrCompanyName = [];
    const arrTelephones = [];
    const arrAddresses = [];

    const { category, city } = this.state;

    const $ = await request({
      uri: `https://www.paginasamarillas.es/search/${category}/all-ma/${city}/all-is/malaga/all-ba/all-pu/all-nc/1?what=carpintero&where=malaga&ub=false&qc=true`,
      transform: body => cheerio.load(body) //una vez hago la peticion lo paso a cheerio para que lo analice
    });

    const profesionals1 = $(pathProfesionals1).each((i, el) =>
      arrCompanyName.push($(el).text())
    );

    const telephones1 = $(pathTelephones1).each((i, el) =>
      arrTelephones.push($(el).text())
    );

    const profesionals2 = $(pathProfesionals2).each((i, el) =>
      arrCompanyName.push($(el).text())
    );

    const telephones2 = $(pathTelephones2).each((i, el) =>
      arrTelephones.push($(el).text())
    );

    const addresses1 = $(pathAddress1).each((i, el) =>
      arrAddresses.push($(el).text())
    );

    console.log(arrAddresses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the `span` tag with `itemprop='streetAddress'` attribute only then you need to remove `*` from the address selector. Currently, Cheerio is trying to get all the tags with `itemprop=streetAddress` **inside and not with** `span`.

Also if you want to select all the addresses from that list you can run a simple query with `$(".listado-item .links span[itemprop='streetAddress']")` then iterate the Cheerio object array.